# Re-gridding global data matrices onto a common grid in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, grid, interpolation, resolution

I have multiple 2D matrices/datasets (.mat files in Matlab) corresponding to different ocean properties (e.g. water depth), on global grids. Each grid has a different resolution, but all of the grids are uniform, node-registered, and there are no missing data (except for cells representing land, which are registered as ‘NaN’). I would like to re-grid them onto a common, node-registered grid of 0.25° resolution, therefore a [1441 x 721] matrix (longitude x latitude).

Dataset1: currently 2/3° resolution [541 x 271]. This needs to be transformed to a higher-resolution (0.25°, [1441 x 721]).

Dataset2: currently 0.1° resolution [3601 x 1801]. This needs to be transformed to a lower-resolution (0.25°, [1441 x 721]).

I already have a suitable land-ocean mask at the desired resolution (0.25° [1441 x 721]), that I can overlay once datasets have been re-gridded. However, the re-gridding/interpolation operation will need to somehow account for coastlines in which there will be both land- ('NaN') and ocean- (numeric values) registered cells.

Many thanks for any help or suggestions in how to do this.

Comment: What do you want us to do for you?

Comment: I would like help or suggestions in writing some code or using a function in Matlab to transform the data from one grid resolution to the the desired resolution

Comment: Of course, but that does not make it a good question.
Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: OK thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1):

Answered from Jonas on MatlabAnswers (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/407564-re-gridding-global-data-matrices-onto-a-common-grid-in-matlab?s_tid=mlc_ans_email_ques)

You can resample your data using griddedinterpolant. It seems to ignore NaNs, which is good in this case.

An example:

```
%original 2D-dataset with some NaNs
V=peaks(100);
[x,y]=ndgrid(1:100,1:100);
V(50:60,50:60)=NaN;
%make interpolant from original data  
F = griddedInterpolant(x,y,V)
%desired resolution
[xi,yi]=ndgrid(1:3:100,1:3:100);
%plot
figure;
subplot(1,2,1)
mesh(x,y,V)
subplot(1,2,2)
mesh(xi,yi,F(xi,yi))
```

You can of course specify interpolation method as well.